# vba search function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a function that find's a string in a worksheet, and sets a range variable with the location of the found phrase. When I try to check if the .find returned a value, I get an error:

```
Public Function ExceptionSearch(ByVal eString As String) As Boolean

Dim pRange As Range
Dim bDT As Boolean
Dim bSVR As Boolean
Dim bMB As Boolean

Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets("worksheet").Activate

With Worksheets("worksheet").Range("a1:a5000")

Set pRange = .Find(eString, LookIn:=xlValues)

If pRange <> "" Then
bDT = True
Else
bDT = False
End If

End With


ExceptionSearch = bDT

End Function
```

I keep getting the error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

This is probably a simple problem, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You should check to make sure pRange exists before checking the value against the blank string.

```
Set pRange = .Find(eString, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not pRange Is Nothing Then
    ' string check here 
End If
```

Comment: hey another quick question, even thought it's not directly related. Is there any way to increment the value of a cell.Row?
For example, can I say usedCell.Row = usedCell.Row + 1?

It doesn't seem to be working in that format.

Comment: @Joe No, I don't believe so, otherwise you could throw off your whole worksheet.  You can assign `usedCell.Row` to a variable and increment that to keep track of it.

Comment: As I'm rereading what I said, I realize I wasn't clear. usedCell is a variable, a bad name to use for an example in this case lol.

Basically I loop through the worksheet by using activesheet.usedrange.cells, and if a certain if clause fails I want to set the position of my cell variable.

Comment: I'd have a little Integer varible keeping track of your current row, then, and when you fail, you'll just use the value of your variable to see where the row was that caused the failure.  And/or use offset to move through rows or columns in your loop.

Comment: Ok so when this trigger proves true I need to increment the row by 1 relational to where it is, but I also need to statically set the column back to 1. 

So I should be able to do rngUsedCell = rngUsedCell.Offset(1,0) to incrememnt the focus by 1 row. But the line rngUsedCell.Column = 1 doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  If you want to move the focus down a row, then yes, use Cell.Offset(1, 0). That will only push the focus down a row, but it won't adjust the column.  If your column is at 1 to begin with, there will be no change.  Column in your case sounds like a property of the Range object. It is read-only, according to the Object Browser in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Since the .Find returns an object, it is equal to `Nothing` if the value is not found.  Change it to:

```
If pRange Is Nothing Then
    bDT = True
Else
    bDT = False
End If
```

Or really, you could eliminate the `if/else` block altogether and just do `ExceptionSearch=pRange Is Nothing` since `pRange Is Nothing` will come back with a `Boolean` anyway

Comment: thanks guys, the if Not pRange is Nothing worked like a charm.